# calculate time difference of consecutive row dates in SQL

Tags: sql

Hello I am trying to calculate the time difference of 2 consecutive rows for Date (either in hours or Days), as attached in the image
Highlighted in Yellow is the result I want which is basically the difference of the date in that row and 1 above.
How can we achieve it in the SQL? Attached is my complex code which has the rest of the fields in it

[image]

```
with cte 
as
(

select m.voucher_no, CONVERT(VARCHAR(30),CONVERT(datetime, f.action_Date, 109),100) as action_date,f.col1_Value,f.col3_value,f.col4_value,f.comments,f.distr_user,f.wf_status,f.action_code,f.wf_user_id 
from attdetailmap m
LEFT JOIN awftaskfin f ON f.oid = m.oid and f.client ='PC'
where f.action_Date !=''  and action_date between '$?datef' and '$?datet'

),
.*select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY action_Date,distr_user,wf_Status,wf_user_id order by action_Date,distr_user,wf_Status,wf_user_id ) as row_no_1 from cte

cte2 as 
(
select *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY voucher_no,action_Date,distr_user,wf_Status,wf_user_id order by voucher_no ) as row_no_1 from cte 
)
select distinct(v.dim_value) as resid,c.voucher_no,CONVERT(datetime, c.action_Date, 109) as action_Date,c.col4_value,c.comments,c.distr_user,v.description,c.wf_status,c.action_code,  c.wf_user_id,v1.description as name,r.rel_value as pay_office,r1.rel_value as site

from cte2  c 

LEFT OUTER JOIN aagviuserdetail v ON v.user_id = c.distr_user
LEFT OUTER JOIN aagviuserdetail v1 ON v1.user_id = c.wf_user_id
LEFT OUTER JOIN ahsrelvalue r ON r.resource_id = v.dim_Value and r.rel_Attr_id = 'P1' and r.period_to = '209912'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ahsrelvalue r1 ON r1.resource_id = v.dim_Value and r1.rel_Attr_id = 'Z1' and r1.period_to = '209912'

where c.row_no_1 = '1'  and r.rel_value like '$?site1' and voucher_no like '$?trans' 

order by voucher_no,action_Date
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

The key idea is `lag()`.  However, date/time functions vary among databases.  So, the idea is:

```
select t.*,
       (date - lag(date) over (partition by transaction_no order by date)) as diff
from t;
```

I should note that this exact syntax might not work in your database -- because `-` may not even be defined on date/time values.  However, `lag()` is a standard function and should be available.

For instance, in SQL Server, this would look like:

```
select t.*,
       datediff(second, lag(date) over (partition by transaction_no order by date), date) / (24.0 * 60 * 60) as diff_days
from t;
```

Comment: I have added my complex code. You will notice there are some partitions already in it. Do you recommend fitting it somewhere there?

Comment: Let me know if you can suggest something in my existing code

Comment: Gordon's answer here is a good answer to the question (based on the original structure provided). For location, I suggest putting it in your final SELECT, after the `c.voucher_no,CONVERT(datetime, c.action_Date, 109) as action_Date` as those seem to be the relevant fields. However, I notice that c.action_date is a VARCHAR not a datetime field. That means that sorting (and therefore LAG) will be incorrect. At worst you'll need to convert it to a datetime as part of the LAG; better to update your code to avoid doing the 3-way CONVERTs you're doing.